# Need help to begin with Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am just a beginner in eclipse rcp and I'm feeling it hard to understand the concepts. Infact I struggling to create a button, somebody please give a good suggestion as to how to start with rcp.

Answer (score 8):

The **[Vogella's tutorial on RCP](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html)** is both up-to-date and quite complete, and updated for E4, including its `E4 CSS Spy` and other Eclipse e4 Tools..

[image: Eclipse 4 Application Project]

You can also read about the [difference between plug-in, feature and product in eclipse RCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692048/what-is-the-difference-between-plug-in-feature-and-product-in-eclipse-rcp/2692822#2692822).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159190/eclipse-rcp-toolbar-buttons-with-the-eclipse-look on the button topic.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505292/swt-jface-or-eclipse-rcp on RCP in general

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the RCP resources mentioned by VonC, for lower-level stuff (you mentioned  creating a button) check out the SWT snippets: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at the built-in example applications , especially the mail application they're quite helpful.

And every time you run into something you don't understand - check out the **plugin.xml** the answer is probably there =)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to online resources, there are some good introductory books, including:

- Eric Clayberg and Dan Rubel's "Eclipse plugins," Addison-Wesley.
- Vladimir Silva's "Practical Eclipse Rich Client Platform Projects", Apress.
- Other books in the Addison-Wesley Eclipse series, such as Steve Northover and Mike Wilson's "SWT: The standard widget toolkit" (from 2004, but still useful).

Answer (score 0):

You can get started quickly with the [RCP How-To](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_RCP_How-to).